# 500 Internal Server error when using curl on an aspx page with SSL

Tags: ssl, curl

I'm trying to access an aspx webpage using curl but it returns 500 internal server error. It doesn't require any credentials or POST variables I know of, but I think I'm missing something, because when I try to access it from my browser, it does work. The page is just a form with two fields to be filled and POSTed.

```
curl -L https://my.website.com
```

Do I need to make any changes to my curl script?

ps. I don't have access to the server or the server's logs

Comment: Does your curl support https? Check with curl --version

Comment: libcurl/7.16.3 OpenSSL/0.9.7l zlib/1.2.3
...
Features: GSS-Negotiate IPv6 Largefile NTLM SSL libz so the problem doesn't lie there.. I can also use it on other ssl pages but not the specific one, for some reason

Comment: My guess would be that the target server wants a UserAgent string, and your tool isn't sending one.

Answer (score 3):

Some things to try and ideas:

1. trace your manual access with e.g. Fiddler or httpfox or firebug.  You might see something more elaborate than you have see already (like a 301/302 response, I assume that you added -L to handle such a possibility?
2. as it works when you check out the page via a browser, the page might attempt a referrer check and fail miserably because there is no referrer (hence the 500, a server-side error).  The dump you created in 1. will show you what to insert with curl's -e option.